# First Haskell program

Tags: haskell

i write a little code in Haskell to learn haskell. It looks like:

```
first :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
first [] x     = x
first xs y     = y
```

I wanted to express that i get a list([] or xs) and an argument(x or y) and no matter how the lists look like, the argument should presented.

So, when I write the following: first [1,2,3] 4, then ghci says:

```
Couldnt match expected type ´a0 -> t´ wth actual type ´[t0]´. Relevant bindings       
include it :: t(boudn at <>:6:1)but its type ´[t 0]´ has none
In the expression : [1,2,3] 4
In an equation for ´it´: it = [1,2,3] 4
```

How can i fix it? What mistakes i´ve made? Can someone help me?

Comment: If you don't care about the first argument at all, why not simply `first _ x = x`?

Comment: Did you write `[1,2,3,4] 4` instead of `first [1,2,3,4] 4`?

Comment: no, i write: [1,2,3] 4 ...and then that error above appears. When i write [1,2,3,4] 4 then I have the error: Non-exhaustive patterns in function first

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you use `[1,2,3,4] 4` instead of `first [1,2,3,4] 4`.

```
> [1,2,3,4] 4

<interactive>:1:0:
    Couldn't match expected type `t1 -> t' against inferred type `[a]'
    In the expression: [1, 2, 3, 4] 4
    In the definition of `it': it = [1, 2, 3, 4] 4
```

---

By the way, your definition of `first` is the same as the following:

```
first :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
first _ x     = x
```

which means no matter what the first argument is, always returns the second argument.

Comment: I think in that case the error report will also include: `The function [1, 2, 3, 4] is applied to one argument`. :)

Comment: @Sibi The asker tried to evaluate `it = [1,2,3] 4`, as indicated in the last line of the error message.

Comment: Aha, ok...is the sign "_"  a wildcard, which i know from other programming languages ?   To the beginning of your answer:No, i write first [1,2,3] 4   But how can i change the function declarations without a wildcard ?

Comment: @user3097712 Yes, some kind of, `_` means something like "I do not care what the value at that position may be" :-) In technical term, `_` means pattern matching everything but binding to nothing.

Comment: now, when i write : first[1,2,3,4] 4 . It says: Non-exhaustive patterns in function first.

Comment: @user3097712 Which definition of `first` are you using?

Comment: sry, but: what you mean with definition? I have in the file first.hs the two function declarations, after the type declaration. And when i type first[1,2,3] 4, then it says: Exception...non-exhaustive pattern in function first

Comment: @user3097712 The definition of `first` in your question should not throw this exception, neither should the definition in my answer. What is the exactly contents of your `first.hs`?

Comment: uhm...its weird...i close the ghci and open it again. try the same as i write above and you are right. the code works without error messages. I had some versions of first.hs at the beginning. maybe i had one of the other wrong versions open and that could be the reason, why i had the error messages and you had nothing. but, thank you for your help :) it works now...as you said.